# Set background color of NSWindow with appearance set

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am using the following code on my NSWindow so that all my buttons, pop ups, etc. are in a dark mode tint:

```
[self.window setAppearance:[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark]];
```

But I want to set a custom window background color instead of the black color which is set as default for the Vibrant Dark Appearance. Calling this line without the appearance works otherwise fails to set:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"backgroundColor"]];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a view with a background color and use It as your window's background.

[Take a look at this sample app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/361frcrvcrp4rxv/Colored%20Vibrant%20Background.zip?dl=0).

[image: NSWindow with vibrant dark color and background color]

Comment: As your link is expired, Can you add required part of  sample code.